# Why does F# prefer lists over arrays?

Tags: data-structures, f#

I'm trying to learn F# and was watching a video when something odd (at least, to me) came up. The video in question is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxL9sfVz4IE&feature=related) and the relevant part starts at 2:30 for those interested. But basically, the guy says that F# makes it awkward to work with arrays and that the designers did so on purpose because lists are easier to "prepend and append".

The question that immediately sprang to mind: isn't easy prepending and appending something that should be frowned upon in an immutable language? Specifically, I'm thinking of C#'s Lists where you can do something like `List.Add(obj);` and mutate the list. With an array you'd have to create an entirely new array, but that's also what would need to happen in an immutable language.

So why do the designers of F# prefer lists? What is the fundamental difference in an immutable environment between a list and an array? What am I missing? Are lists in F# really linked lists?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In functional languages lists are usually single-linked lists. I.e. it is not necessary to copy the complete list. Instead prepending (often called cons) is a O(1) operation and you can still use the old list, because lists are immutable.

Answer (score 53):

I would disagree that "F# makes it awkward to work with arrays".  In fact, F# makes working with arrays quite nice compared to most languages.

For example, F# has literal array construction: `let arr = [|1;2;3;4;|]`.  And perhaps even cooler, pattern matching on arrays:

```
match arr with
| [|1;2;_;_|] -> printfn "Starts with 1;2"
| [|_;_;3;4|] -> printfn "Ends with 3;4"
| _ -> printfn "Array not recognized"
```

As to why immutable singly linked lists are preferred in functional programming like F#, there's a lot to say, but the short answer is that it allows an O(1) prepend efficiency, and allows the implementation to share nodes, so it is easy on memory.  For example,

```
let x = [2;3]
let y = 1::x
```

Here y is created by prepending 1 to x, but x is neither modified nor copied, so making y was very cheap. We can see a bit how this is possible, since x points to the head, 2, of the initially constructed list and can only move forward, and since the elements of the list it points to can't be mutated, it doesn't matter that y shares nodes with it.

Comment: Builtin pattern matching on arrays is rarely useful, though, since it's limited to arrays of specific length.  Normally you're doing matches of the form | a :: b :: restOfList, and there's nothing like that for arrays.

Answer (score 15):

First of all, arrays are pretty low-level data structure and they are really only useful if you know the lenght of the array when creating it. That's not often the case and that's a reason why C# programmers use `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` and F# programmers use F# `list<T>`.

The reason why F# prefers its own functional list rather than using .NET `List<T>` is that functional languages prefer immutable types. Instead of modifying the object by calling `list.Add(x)`, you can create new list with items added to the front by writing `let newList = x::list`.

I also agree with Stephen that using arrays in F# is not awkward at all. If you know the number of elements you're working with or you're transforming some existing data source, then working with arrays is quite easy:

```
/ You can create arrays using `init`
let a = Array.init 10 (fun i -> (* calculate i-th element here *) )

// You can transform arrays using `map` and `filter`
a |> Array.map (fun n -> n + 10)
  |> Array.filter (fun n -> n > 12)

// You can use array comprehensions:
let a2 = [| for n in a do
              if n > 12 then yield n + 10 |]
```

This is essentially the same as processing lists - there you would use list comprehensions `[ ... ]` and list processing functions such as `List.map` etc. The difference really appears just when initializing the list/array.

Answer (score 14):

> F# makes it awkward to work with arrays

F# provides many features that make it easier to work with arrays than in other languages, including array literals, array patterns and higher-order functions.

> The question that immediately sprang to mind: isn't easy prepending and appending something that should be frowned upon in an immutable language?

I believe you have misunderstood what that statement means. When people talk about prepending and appending in the context of purely functional data structures they are referring to the creation of a new collection that is derived (and shared most of its internals) with an existing collection.

> So why do the designers of F# prefer lists?

F# inherited some list-related capabilities from OCaml which inherited them from Standard ML and ML because singly-linked immutable lists are very useful in the context of their application domain (metaprogramming) but I would not say that the designers of F# prefer lists.

> What is the fundamental difference in an immutable environment between a list and an array?

In F#, lists provide O(1) prepend and append and O(n) random access whereas arrays provide O(n) prepend and append and O(1) random access. Arrays can be mutated but lists cannot.

> What am I missing?

Basic knowledge of purely functional data structures. Read Okasaki.

> Are lists in F# really linked lists?

Yes. Specifically, singly-linked immutable lists. In fact, in some MLs the `list` type can be defined as:

```
type 'a list =
  | ([])
  | (::) of 'a * 'a list
```

This is why the `::` operator is a constructor and not a function so you cannot write `(::)` as you can with, for example, `(+)`.

Comment: Why append in F# is O(1)? I think it should be O(n). As a singly-linked list, you have only the reference to the head, so need to travel all the way to the tail to append an element, so O(n). Prepend is O(1) is correct, because we have reference to the head.

Comment: Theoretically a singly linked list can have two sentinel values so prepending/appending can both be O(1). Not sure about F# implementation though.

Answer (score 6):

An F# list is more like the following datastructure - a single linked list:

```
public class List<T> {

    public List(T item, List<T> prev) { /*...*/ }

    public T Item { get; }
    public List<T> Prev { get; }
}
```

So when a new list is created, it is actually creating a single node with a reference to the first element of the previous list, rather than copying the entire array.